# Print from java to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, web

i am trying to create a Facebook oAuth code which in the end will print user's First Name, Last Name,Email etc on browser. This will be made with java and jsp. So here is my java code

```
public class MainMenu extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String code="";

public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {      

    code = req.getParameter("code");
    if (code == null || code.equals("")) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "ERROR: Didn't get code parameter in callback.");
    }
    FBConnection fbConnection = new FBConnection();
    String accessToken = fbConnection.getAccessToken(code);

    FBGraph fbGraph = new FBGraph(accessToken);
    String graph = fbGraph.getFBGraph();
    Map<String, String> fbProfileData = fbGraph.getGraphData(graph);
    ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
    out.println("<h1>Facebook Login using Java</h1>");
    out.println("<h2>Application Main Menu</h2>");
    out.println("<div>Welcome "+fbProfileData.get("first_name"));
    out.println("<div>Your Email: "+fbProfileData.get("email"));
    out.println("<div>You are "+fbProfileData.get("gender"));


}
```

}

and i have an empty jsp file.

Comment: try using `response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();`

Comment: getWriter is not applicable for the arguments.(String) any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that i had this error message.

Comment: `response.getWriter();` does not take any arguments

Comment: aa ok i didn't know that sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpServletResponse` `res` to do that:

```
res.getWriter().write("<h2>Application Main Menu</h2>" +
                    "<h1>Facebook Login using Java</h1>" +
                    "<div>Welcome "+fbProfileData.get("first_name") +
                    "<div>Your Email: "+fbProfileData.get("email") + 
                    "<div>You are "+fbProfileData.get("gender"));
res.getWriter().flush();
res.getWriter().close();
```

Comment: getWriter is not applicable for the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as Scary suggested, try using,

`PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()`

As this basically does the similar work of, System.out.println as in Java.